# avplayer with slow-internet connection not working after first frame

Tags: swift, uiview, avplayer

my problem is that when having very bad connection,the activtiy indicator start animating till first frame in video is shown,then disappear thinking is the video is playing,but the video stops playing stuck on loaded first frame,until the whole video is loaded then its resume playing,how to show activity indicator while video is stuck on frame and buffering ,then play until next loaded frame ?

- notes:

  - it's working when internet connetion is off  ,video is played until the loaded frame and activity indicator is shown,then when turn on video us resumed to play and activity indicator is hidden
  - it's working when normal internet connection is present
  - removing and showing indicator using override observevalue for key path
       "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges"/"currentItem.playbackBufferEmpty"

i made a uiview class with avplayer in it

```
import UIKit

import AVKit
import AVFoundation
class videoplaying: UIView {
    override static var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self;
    }
    var playerlayer: AVPlayerLayer{
        return layer as! AVPlayerLayer;
    }
    var player: AVPlayer?{
        get{
            return playerlayer.player
        }
        set {
            playerlayer.player = newValue
        }
    }
    var playetitem: AVPlayerItem?


}
```

i assigned a uivew in uicollectioncell to this class(using storyboard)
avplayer starts playing and adding observes when pressing play in uicollectioncell

```
@IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {
        activityindicator.isHidden = false
        activityindicator.startAnimating()
        self.butttoonheight.isHidden = true
        self.postimage.isHidden = true
        let url2 = URL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
        let avplayer = AVPlayer(url: url2! )
        let playeritem = AVPlayerItem(url: url2!)
        //videoss is class of type uiview
        videoss.playetitem = playeritem
        videoss.playerlayer.player = avplayer
      videoss.player?.play()
        videoss.player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)
        videoss.player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: .new
            , context: nil)
         videoss.player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.playbackBufferEmpty", options: .new, context: nil)
        playying.isHidden = false
    }

//observing when video is playing


//playpause button to play or pause video while bad network is present video is stuck on first frame and playorpause is not changing while pressed
     @IBAction func playorpause(_ sender: Any) {
            if videoss.player?.timeControlStatus == AVPlayerTimeControlStatus.paused{
                videoss.player?.play()
                playying.setImage(UIImage(named: "pas50"), for: .normal)
            }
            if videoss.player?.timeControlStatus == AVPlayerTimeControlStatus.playing{
                videoss.player?.pause()
                playying.setImage(UIImage(named: "p24"), for: .normal)
            }
        }
        override public func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
            if keyPath == "rate"{
                print(videoss.player?.rate)
                if  videoss.player?.rate == 0.0 {
                    print("dawdaopwdaopwdipo")
                }
            }
            if keyPath == "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges"{
                print("its is working")
                activityindicator.stopAnimating()
                activityindicator.isHidden = true
            }
            if keyPath == "currentItem.playbackBufferEmpty"
            {
                activityindicator.startAnimating()
                activityindicator.isHidden = false
                print("pkawdawdawd")
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding a timer that runs ever 0.3 seconds,evrry 0.3seconds it checks the current time of the video if current time equals previous time then the video is not playing activity indicator is shown,if not video if playing activity indicators was hidden,also you need to check if the users pause the video,an advantage is you also get the current time also in the same function.
What i tried also was seeing rate of the video ,but over slow internet the rate was always giving that is playing,but it wasn’t,which didn’t help